# Page.php wont show added content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a set of logos on my index.php in WP and they appear at the buttom, right where i want.

But they do not appear on all pages, if i add the exact code on the exact place in page.php it wont show, on any page in my site, and i need the logos to appear on all pages.
Am i inserting the code on the right file?

Index.php and Page.php end exactly the same so this is both ends with my code:

```
<?php 

    lets_make_carousel();

?>

    <div id="footerlogos">
    <div id="logotonal"><a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="/new/wp-content/themes/music/images/footerlogos/tonal.png" /></a></div>

    <div id="logoah"><a href="#">
    <img src="/new/wp-content/themes/music/images/footerlogos/ah.png" /></a></div>

    <div id="logotranceil"><a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="/new/wp-content/themes/music/images/footerlogos/tranceil.png" /></a></div>

    <div id="logobpm"><a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="/new/wp-content/themes/music/images/footerlogos/bpm.png" /></a></div>

    <div id="logoakum"><a href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="/new/wp-content/themes/music/images/footerlogos/akum.png" /></a></div>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Put that in footer.php. =]

See how it calls get_footer() at the bottom? That is getting the footer from footer.php, if I recall correctly.

Either way, it belongs there.

Comment: i agree but i am trying to insert those icons in a special field created by make_carousel

Comment: Edit: Actually Reigal's idea sounds better.

Comment: It actually is...it worked as expected..but what if i want to add a different element lets say, on the middle of the page, to show on all pages?

Comment: make a function in `functions.php` then call that function... where you want it in every page...or make a template file... there are many ways to achieved that.. depends on your situation...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's falling back to another template you're not aware of (maybe it's a child theme falling back to the parent?). Try echoing out the page template that you're currently on to test...

```
<div><strong>Current template:</strong> <?php get_current_template( true ); ?></div>
```

More info at this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page